# UIScrollView: difference between setContentOffset:animated and scrollRectToVisible:animated

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have read Apple Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS but still confused about the following part:

> **Scrolling to a Specific Offset**
>
> Scrolling to a specific top-left location (the contentOffset property)
>   can be accomplished in two ways. The setContentOffset:animated: method
>   scrolls the content to the specified content offset. If the animated
>   parameter is YES, the scrolling will animate from the current position
>   to the specified position at a constant rate. If the animated
>   parameter is NO, the scrolling is immediate and no animation takes
>   place. In both cases, the delegate is sent a scrollViewDidScroll:
>   message. If animation is disabled, or if you set the content offset by
>   setting the contentOffset property directly, the delegate receives a
>   single scrollViewDidScroll: message. If animation is enabled, then the
>   delegate receives a series of scrollViewDidScroll: messages as the
>   animation is in progress. When the animation is complete, the delegate
>   receives a scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: message.
>
> **Making a rectangle visible**
>
> It is also possible to scroll a rectangular area so that it is
>   visible. This is especially useful when an application needs to
>   display a control that is currently outside the visible area into the
>   visible view. The scrollRectToVisible:animated: method scrolls the
>   specified rectangle so that it is just visible inside the scroll view.
>   If the animated parameter is YES, the rectangle is scrolled into view
>   at a constant pace. As with setContentOffset:animated:, if animation
>   is disabled, the delegate is sent a single scrollViewDidScroll:
>   message. If animation is enabled, the delegate is sent a series of
>   scrollViewDidScroll: messages as animation progresses. In the case of
>   scrollRectToVisible:animated: the scroll view’s tracking and dragging
>   properties are also NO.
>
> If animation is enabled for scrollRectToVisible:animated:, the
>   delegate receives a scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: message,
>   providing notification that the scroll view has arrived at the
>   specified location and animation is complete.

I think it is quite similar between setContentOffset:animated and scrollRectToVisible:animated, could someone give some hints about them?

And scrollRectToVisible:animated: is similar to scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:animated: too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer:

**setContentOffset:animated** preserves the *zoomscale*.

**scrollRectToVisible:animated** may change it.

Comment: If you use setContentOffset:animated: you can scroll outside the contentSize.

Comment: @GustafRosenblad That is not true, you cannot scroll outside the contentSize you would have to add content inset.

Comment: @OscarGomez What I mean is that you can set content offset -100 and it will scroll outside the range.

Comment: @OscarGomez: I also have the scrolled outside issue, that not so practical